# Как отправить три поля в одну строку?

Tags: android

Как отправить три поля в одну строку?
В моём случае отправляется последнее значение..

```
//Email subject
                message.setSubject(etName.getText().toString().trim());
                message.setSubject(etPhone.getText().toString().trim());
                message.setSubject(etEmail.getText().toString().trim());
```

Необходимо чтобы заголовок выглядел следующим образом: Ivan, +7 (966) 666-66-66, example@gmail.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Самое очевидное вот так:

```
message.setSubject(etName.getText().toString().trim()+", "+etPhone.getText().toString().trim()+", "+ etEmail.getText().toString().trim());
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, всё работает именно так, как нужно!